# How to see the names of files that Dropbox is uploading/downloading?

Tags: files, dropbox

I would like to know the names of the files that Dropbox is currenting upload and downloading.  How to best do that?  Happy with either a GUI or command line answer...

Comment: Although OP has signed on recently he has apparently abandoned this question. Although Dropbox has recently gained media attention this question is 5 years old and addressees a version of Ubuntu that is EOL. VTC as `not reproducible.

Comment: I don't think this is no-repro @WinEunuuchs2Unix as it's not a version-specific issue. We could certainly answer this question for current Dropbox versions (is there a dupe target?) or answer to say it's impossible to access such information. No need to close I think

Comment: @Zanna today one would click the Dropbox icon as per their website: https://www.dropbox.com/help/syncing-uploads/check-progress Five years ago (under Ubuntu 12.04) the method was probably different. File progress displays are built into virtually all modern applications making this type of question unnecessary. Even the humble bash apps I write popup a progress display when a process takes longer than 1 second. I guess we could reopen and post an answer though...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix you can post the up-to-date answer. No need for an historical answer

Comment: @Zanna The question is already on hold. It would have to be reopened within five days before it becomes closed....